# optional string parameter in extension method

Tags: c#, extension-methods, optional-arguments

I have a line of code that says

```
string sendQueueName = ESResource.Service.TOPICA.Src();
```

The way the class is laid out is as follows:-

```
public static class ESResource{
    static ESResource() {
        //initialization code
    }
//other declarations and definitions

    public enum Service { TOPICA,TOPICB,TOPICC };
    public static string Path(this Service sn) { return FromKey(sn, "PATH"); }
    public static string Src(this Service sn) { return FromKey(sn, "SRC"); }
}
```

I have a functionality that requires me to be able to pass in a string env 
like this

```
string sendQueueName = ESResource.Service.TOPICA.Src(env);
```

But when i try to modify my Src function to support the above function call like this :

```
public static string Src(this Service sn, string env=""){ return FromKey(sn, "PATH", env); }
```

It says it cannot find a function with one parameter. What is the best way to pass in env which is an optional parameter?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't make much sense. How can there be two `ESResource` classes? And what is `TPSDERIVATIVESQUEUE`?

Comment: overloading....  Don't modify your `Src` function, create another one.

Comment: Sorry about the typo. Please see the edit. @Ben Voigt ..I tried that as well but i get an error that says "No overload for method 'Src' takes 1 arguments".Am i doing it right?           public static string Src(this Service sn, string env)              { return FromKey(sn, "SRC", env); }

Comment: @AnushaPachunuri: That looks ok.  Can you put a complete minimal example on ideone.com or another online compiler?

Comment: What does the FromKey method look like?

Comment: I removed what i am doing with env in this function just to avoid confusion... public static string FromKey(this Service sn, string key) { return (ESResource.Variable as IDictionary<string, object>)[ESResource.Variable.Environment + "_" + key + "_" + Enum.GetName(typeof(Service), sn)]; }